# Reset signal in Godot

Tags: godot-4

Is there a way to reset a signal in Godot 4.x?

Yeah... odd question but hear me out.

```
signal hit
```

and at some point:

```
hit.reset() # or something like that
```

A signal is a good way to determine if an enemy has been hit (single hit destruction) and therefore killed.

But in another scenario where a player crashes into something, the player is revived and that signal needs to be reset. - Might not be the best use of a signal here, but that's why I'm asking the question.

And since a signal is really a kind of variable, it can get reset, can't it?

Comment: _the player is revived and that signal needs to be reset._ Reset to what? A signal is not a kind of flag. You can emit a signal as many times as you need ;)

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. Signals are just messages that nodes emit when something specific happens to them. Other nodes can connect to that signal and call a function when the event occurs. So either you're generating continually or retaining the state in a node. If you've run into a specific problem, please edit to include how you are generating & processing the signal related to the state that you wish to reset.

Comment: reset to whatever state it was *before* it got triggered

Comment: This isn't a thing. How did you arrive to the idea that you need to reset a signal? I'm guessing that looking at what you connected to the signal and how you emit it might be a good place to start. Chances are you need to reset something else, and the signal is fine. Barring that, you might need an alternative mechanism for communication other than signals, but I'm not venturing to suggest something without more context. Edit: Just after writing that, this came to mind: do you happen to need to connect the signal again (to a new object since the old one was destroyed)? That makes some sense.

Comment: It was the latter. I got around around it with a simple function call and a boolean. But the question persisted.